# Bind a function to SVG element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

In my `ReactJS` application, I've some SVG shapes like this;

```js
function clipData(svg, cx, cy) {

    var clip = svg.append("defs")
        .append("clipPath") // define a clip path
        .attr("id", "clip") // give the clipPath an ID
        .append("circle") // shape it as an ellipse
        .attr("id", "my-circle")
        .attr("cx", 100) // position the x-centre
        .attr("cy", 80) // position the y-centre
        .attr("r", 80) // set the x radius
        .attr("fill", "yellow")

    svg.append("circle") // shape it as an ellipse
        .attr("cx", 100) // position the x-centre
        .attr("cy", 80) // position the y-centre
        .attr("r", 80) // set the x radius
        .attr("fill", "red")


    var g = svg.append("g")
        .datum({
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        })
        .attr("id", "child")
        //.attr("transform", function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ' '+ d.y + ')'; })

        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);

            })
            .on("drag", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.x) + "," + (d3.event.y) + ")");
                d3.select("#svgGreen").selectAll("*").remove();
                clipData(svg, d3.event.x + cx, d3.event.y + cy);

            })
            .on("end", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
            }));


    g.append("line")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("x1", cx)
        .attr("y1", cy)
        .attr("x2", cx + 100)
        .attr("y2", cy + 100)
        .style("stroke", "purple")
        .style("stroke-width", 12)

}

var svg = d3.select("#svgGreen");
var cx = 100,
    cy = 80,
    x = 0,
    y = 0;

clipData(svg, cx, cy);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  className="clip-path" id="svgGreen">
</svg>
```

Now I want to bind a function with this `svg` that will some how update some states, When I do something like this;

```
svg.call(functionName(Params))
```

It starts re-rendering the component and at the end application gets crashed with this error

[image]

I even tried this one;

```
svg.call(() => { // write all code here })
```

and also this one;

```
svg.call(() => functionName(params))
```

All these ended into crashing application.

> Can someone guide me what should I do to avoid this crash ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure which `call` function you run but all functions I've found on d3.js and even the JavaScript `Function.call` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [D3-Selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.0/README.md#selection_call))method have the following similar syntax:

```js
// from MDN
function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)

// d3 Selection.call
selection.call(function[, arguments…])
```

As I'm guessing you run a D3 function, you have to put in a function definition/reference instead of calling it inside.

Instead of:

```js
svg.call(functionName(Params))
```

just reference it and set your arguments behind:

```js
svg.call(functionName, Params)

// maybe with a bind
svg.call(functionName.bind(thisValue), Params)
```

---

### Edit: Tip

If an `Maximum update depth exceeded`-Error occurs, it is often a callback function which is called at render time which itself triggers a new rendering (instead of passing it down).